# Searching in .csv files on Android smartphone

Tags: android, database, data, csv, database-browser

I am looking for an app that allows easy search within .csv files.

Minimal features

- can somehow read .csv files
- allows to search in them (searching for exact match of string in any column) is sufficient
- can show multiple search results at once if multiple are matching
- works on Android devices
- preferably: open source project
- nice to have: show search results as one types

I am fine with intermediary (and having some sqlite viewer and loading files into database)

why I am looking for it:

I have several .csv files with things like books that I have read, recording of things that I bought or address data.

In some cases it would be nice to access them on the phone - for example to check what I read something from specific author or past price of some item.

Comment: Do you mind using a terminal and command-line on the your phone? If so, you can run a command like: grep -r "my string" ... . I can write full answer if interested. There was also an "Android grep" app.

Comment: @ZZ Is it requiring a rooted phone?

Comment: No rooting required. I have just entered answer below. Not updated in a while but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small app called [aGrep](https://apkpure.com/agrep/jp.sblo.pandora.aGrep) which I use for such search on an old Android. It is open-source and works like "grep" but with an interface.

- User can specify file extension types e.g. csv, txt
- User can specify directory to search
- It can also read SDcard.
  etc

It has not been updated in a while, but does the job.

Repository: https://github.com/jiro-aqua/aGrep

Answer (score 0):

You can use markor from https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.gsantner.markor a markdown text editor that also supports csv files.

Once the csv is loaded you can switch to preview-mode where you can see the data in a tabular layout and use the search-function to find matching lines

[image]

For details see https://github.com/gsantner/markor/blob/master/doc/2023-06-02-csv-readme.md